What is the meaning of reason, and do all animals possess that ability?
Aristotle defined man as the
ζωον λογικόν
Which translates as "logical living thing".
So it appears Aristotle didn't think non-human animals have the ability to reason.
Was he correct?
If you define reasoning as logical thinking, then since non-human animals don't generally think as we do, it follows that they can't reason.
So this raises my other question.

What is reason? Is reason a non-verbal ability?  That is, is it intuitive?


I think there is a big difference between "humans are logical creatures" and "not only humans have logic", right?

@MikeSong, yes there's a significant difference between those two statements.  I am of the position that reason is a mentally 'silent' ability, meaning thought is not a prerequisite to reason, because I have observed that all animals can reason.  They figure things out like,if I want to continue to live, then I must eat and drink, I want to continue to live, therefore I must eat and drink.  They reason, and they don't think to do it.

@MikeSong Your reasoning would be sound if we divorced it from the statement's context. If I am not mistaken, Arisotole here is defining the genus of "human", meaning the above statement contains the minimal description to differentiate "human" from "not human", meaning that the description "rational animal" is unique to the genus of "human" according to Aristotle.

@Max Maxman I also lean towards Aristotle's original statement emphasizing the characteristic of logic in humans, rather than saying that all animals have logic and humans are just one of them. Just like when we say this is a table made of wood, this statement does not mean that all furniture is made of wood and the table is just one of them.

@Max Maxman But the questioner's suggestion is not that reasoning is only possible with the ability to think, and it seems to be correct. We can say that due to the lack of thinking ability, animals execute a relatively mechanical logic with great limitations, but we cannot say that their behavior lacks logic.
But I think this should be the questioner's viewpoint, not Aristotle's viewpoint.

@MikeSong Aristotle is not emphasizing the characteristic of logic in humans, rather he is defining them by it such that if anything is an animal and rational, then it is a human and vice versa. Hence, according to Aristotle's definition, if we say some animals (like dogs for example) are rational, then we are in essence saying that they are humans.

@Max Maxman Okay, your description is more accurate. According to Aristotle's definition, can a logical robot be considered a human?

@MikeSong No, as the robot is not an animal (both conditions must be fulfilled ["animal" and "rational"])

Some animals can reason a bit. Crows, octopuses, chimpanzees can solve puzzles.
Reason is complex problem-solving ability. It's not necessarily about deductive logic, but can be. Solving any puzzle of deductive logic certainly requires reason.
Reason is not necessarily entirely verbal - it could involve turning over shapes in your mind non-verbally, picturing the way forward. But humans do reason a lot better because we have language. Language is a force multiplier for reason.
Reason is distinguished from mere instinct or mere memory. It has to involve combining previous ideas in multiple steps to solve a novel problem. Just remembering something or relying on instinct is sufficient to solve some problems, but not really novel ones.

Reason can be defined as the ability to take in information, think about it, and make a decision about it. This is definitely visible in animals, just not at the same level as humans, certainly.

It is quite difficult to understand his way of thinking from our (modern world) perspective. Aristotle in his differentiation of plants, animals and humans, attributes to λογικό exactly these aspects that an animal mind does not have relative to human. Λογικό is not tautological to reasoning.

In animalism humans are basically the same as animals, in sharing the characteristics of being physical and instinctive.  Under that doctrine, physical characteristics rather than mental characteristics differentiate man from other animals.

@lee pappas, I don't,t know about you but I like to consider myself as in a different mental level than my cat.

if I take away supermarkets, cars, running water, and all other amenities of civilization can you survive as well as your mentally inferior cat?  Or is it a better hunter than you?

@lee pappas Don't underestimate human survival ability. These civilization facilities are built by humans, not by anyone. In other words, it is humanity that created civilization, not civilization that created humanity. Before civilization, humans, like all animals, had their own place in the cruel world of beasts. Just look at our cousin chimpanzees and you'll know that they're not at the bottom of their food in the wild.

Reading Descartes, exactly at the same time that he says that his existence comes from the fact that he exists, he denies that a dog can think, because otherwise it could exist too, which would bring up a lot of theological conflicts. Honestly, it was when I read this passage as a teenager that it convinced me otherwise. Perhaps thinking has nothing to do with human language.
The twentieth century had a certain fetish with language, imagining that the symbol was the essence of thought. To paraphrase Robert Sapolsky in his new book Determined, it is like believing that in the library knowledge is generated by the cards that identify the books.
Teaching philosophy, students once insisted that the sound of the word was part of the message. I found the insistence surprising. Sign languages, of all types around the world, promote communication between people who cannot speak through signs, being languages ​​in every sense. An example may be surprising. A paranoid person may say that God has ordered him to do certain things. When this person uses sign language, he reports that God gestures to him. From there, understanding the relativization of language for animals is one step.
In the nineties, we realized that the generative grammar of language may not follow the logic captured by classical logic, but if we set up neural networks, we can perfectly emulate the language. It took until the twenties before the computer could emulate the necessary calculations at adequate speed, but get it. Today the computer speaks. Try ChatGPT 4.0. It is just the beginning.
Our logic has no relation to this classical logic that we formulated for the sciences. It is much more powerful and relative. In the 20th century, we insisted on trying to make the computer reason in a human way with this Boolean logic, but it was a complete failure. All early attempts at artificial intelligence before neural networks were like this. There was, for example, Prolog, in which we reduced a problem to logical axioms and it would solve it. I did an experiment, at the time, taking a test like those presented in crosswords and I had to admit that the computer and our sophisticated "artificial intelligence" methods were not capable of even solving banal problems.
The Enlightenment, from Laplace to Kant, in its desire to eliminate God from things, ended up creating a mysticism of the self, which exploded in the existentialism of the 20th century. For the only agent to be the human, to be the human will, the human has become a mortal God.
It is Byung-Chul Han who says that this made human beings understand that life is everything. Byung-Chul Han also remembers that Nietzsche had already said that, when God dies, Health appears as divinity.
